# Three.js - Extrude face along its normal vector

Tags: javascript, vector, three.js, geometry

I want to extrude faces from a THREE.Geometry object, so my approach was to:
- specify the faces to extrude
- extract vertices on the outer edges
- Draw a THREE.Shape with those vertices
- Extrude it using THREE.ExtrudeGeometry (I'm actually using a modified version which is not generating front faces, as I'm cloning them by myself to keep original topology).

It seems to work having a CircleGeometry on a XY plane, so extruding on Z direction.
[image]

but if I rotate the circle a bit this is what I get. It extrudes on Z World Axes, not following its local orientation
[image]

I can I solve this? Here's the function I'm using:

```
function faceExtrude( geometry, face_group, amount ) {

if ( geometry.type === "undefined" ) {

    console.log( "faceextrude error" );

    return;

}

//convert face_group to vertex_group
var vertex_group = [];

for ( var i = 0; i < face_group.length; i++ ) {

        //get vertices ID
        var f = face_group[i];
        var a = f.a;
        var b = f.b;
        var c = f.c;

        //clone vertices
        var v1 = geometry.vertices[a].clone();
        var v2 = geometry.vertices[b].clone();
        var v3 = geometry.vertices[c].clone();

        //add them to an array
        vertex_group.push(v1, v2, v3);

}


// Side Faces

var vertsToExtrude = [];


//Get only verts in outer edge
for ( var v = 0; v < vertex_group.length; v++ ) {

    var shareCount = 0;

    //count their presence in each face
    for ( var f = 0; f < face_group.length; f++ ) {

        if( v == face_group[ f ].a || 
            v == face_group[ f ].b ||
            v == face_group[ f ].c ) 
        {

            shareCount++;
        }
    }

    //if < 4 than it's in an outer edge. Add it to an array
    if ( shareCount < 4) {

        vertsToExtrude.push( vertex_group[ v ].clone() );

    }
}


//make a shape with them

var shape = new THREE.Shape();


shape.moveTo( vertsToExtrude[ 0 ].x, vertsToExtrude[ 0 ].y );

for ( var i = 1; i < vertsToExtrude.length; i++ ){

    shape.lineTo( vertsToExtrude[ i ].x, vertsToExtrude[ i ].y );

}

shape.lineTo( vertsToExtrude[ 0 ].x, vertsToExtrude[ 0 ].y );

//extrude it

var extrudeSettings = { amount: amount, steps: 2, bevelEnabled: false };

var sideGeo = new THREE.MyExtrudeGeometry( shape, extrudeSettings );


//Front Faces

var frontGeo = new THREE.Geometry();

for ( var i = 0; i < face_group.length; i++ ) {

        //get vertices ID
        var f = face_group[i];
        var a = f.a;
        var b = f.b;
        var c = f.c;

        //new vertices IDs
        var new_a = frontGeo.vertices.length;
        var new_b = frontGeo.vertices.length + 1;
        var new_c = frontGeo.vertices.length + 2;

        //clone vertices
        var v1 = geometry.vertices[a].clone();
        var v2 = geometry.vertices[b].clone();
        var v3 = geometry.vertices[c].clone();
        frontGeo.vertices.push(v1, v2, v3);

        //translate them depending on "amount"
        v1.z = v1.z + amount;
        v2.z = v2.z + amount;
        v3.z = v3.z + amount;

        //add them to a face 
        var f = new THREE.Face3(new_a, new_b, new_c);
        frontGeo.faces.push(f);

}

frontGeo.computeFaceNormals();

geometry.merge( sideGeo );

geometry.merge( frontGeo );
```

};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm blind. Missed this while reading docs about ExtrudeGeometry:

"extrudePath — THREE.CurvePath. 3d spline path to extrude shape along. (creates Frames if (frames aren't defined)"

Think this is the solution I'm looking for :)

Comment: Can you explain your answer? I am currently trying to define frames for an extrusion and think your solution might help!

Comment: @benjamin if you have a look a the docs (https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/geometries/ExtrudeGeometry) you see you can specify an "extrudePath " property to options parameter of ExtrudeGeometry